# NSView / CALayer subtracting mask

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, quartz-graphics, nsview

I've just wondered about how give negative space to a NSView and and because I can't describe it properly in words I will show you a picture of the desired effect:

http://s16.postimg.org/lci7s2s8l/stackoverflow_problem.jpg

Please don't feel afraid to ask further questions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the options is to setup the following layers' hierarchy:

```
CATextLayer
`-CALayer with desired backgroundColor and CISourceOutCompositing compositingFilter
```

The corresponding code looks like

```
// Setup layer-hosting view.
NSView *view = [[NSView alloc] initWithFrame:viewFrame];
view.wantsLayer = YES;
view.layer = [CALayer layer];
view.layerUsesCoreImageFilters = YES;

CATextLayer *textLayer = [CATextLayer layer];
textLayer.string = @"Masked Text";
textLayer.frame = NSRectToCGRect(viewFrame);
[view.layer addSublayer:textLayer];

CALayer *colorLayer = [CALayer layer];
colorLayer.backgroundColor = [[NSColor greenColor] CGColor];
colorLayer.frame = NSRectToCGRect(viewFrame);
[textLayer addSublayer:colorLayer];

CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CISourceOutCompositing"];
[filter setDefaults];
colorLayer.compositingFilter = filter;
```

**Updated:** to have more flexibility with positioning text you can employ the following hierarchy:

```
CALayer - this layer should stay empty (let's call it emptyLayer)
|- CATextLayer
`- CALayer with CISourceOutCompositing compositingFilter
```

In this case `textLayer` can be smaller than `emptyLayer` and can be positioned the way you want.

Comment: Great answer. Is there a solution for shifting the text of the CATextLayer some pixels downwards without moving the mask, so that I can vertically center the text.

Comment: Updated the answer with new hierarchy which allows to move `textLayer` down.